# YouTube player initialization error in my android app

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api, youtubeplayer

I have an Android app, which uses YouTube videos as a data source and delivers to the users via firebase as a realtime database but from last few days it is showing an error having the following error message when opened to play the content.

> an error occurred while initializing the YouTube player.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt if you would also show how you are initializing the player